# Buddypress reverting code back to original plugin, I lost my all modification to plugin. I am running wp-4.4 and buddypress-2.2.4

Tags: wordpress, file, buddypress, reverting

I have buddypress 2.2.4 installed with wordpress 4.4.

Now issue I am facing is, I did some modification to buddypress plugin in plugin files it self. And its reverting back. Its changing my modified files to its original versions. even I try this in my local and same result.

I ask server guy but he told its buddypress issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you modify a BP file, do you see changes in the browser? Or do the files revert to the original state instantly after closing them in a code editor? What are the file permission settings for the BP plugin files?

What files do you modify and with what changes?

Are you hitting update for the plugin? Plugin updates *always* overwrite local changes as new files are written over the old ones (unless you juggle with write-permissions for the files).

It is not a BuddyPress issue by itself (tried it myself and I could hack the plugin files just fine). It could be the server giving you the illusion of write-allowed files whilst keeping the files unchanged ("reverting"). Or then the plugins are updated constantly, undoing your changes.

The proper way to make modifications is to either use hooks in a plugin or a theme, or copy over the BuddyPress templates to your theme and make modifications there.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick answer. I modified header file. and I can see that change in my browser. and after 4-5 hours its back to its original code. even in my local server in my laptop. So issue is something with buddypress. and its not upgrading plugin because still its shows me new update version available in admin.

Comment: I see. I wonder whether BuddyPress has automatic background security updates available (like WordPress core has), those could trigger the file resets. But as I said, it would be better to create the changed files on the templates that have been copied to the theme's directory (under a `buddypress` folder I presume). This way updates and other related changes keep your changes intact.

Comment: Can you give me function or file path from where they trigger reset in buddypress ?

Comment: I know relatively little about BuddyPress, but perhaps their own documentation can shed light on this.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find any solution to that. but I keep my changes by adding a override files to child theme. because I tried everything and its not stopping reset plugin. 
So finally making override of plugin in child theme solve this issue.